# python df code works outside loop but not inside

Tags: python, loops

Other answers on stackoverflow do adress loop problems but none does address a df outside a loop so I have to ask this question.

I have below code which does exactly what it should grab a table, dataframe it and append it to final_df outside of the loop:

```
empty =[]
final_df= pd.DataFrame(empty, columns =['column_1', 'column_2', 'column_3',
           'column_4', 'report'])

document = Document(targets_in_dir[1])
table = document.tables[2]


data = []

keys = None
for i, row in enumerate(table.rows):
    text = (cell.text for cell in row.cells)

    if i == 0:
        keys = tuple(text)
        continue
    row_data = dict(zip(keys, text))
    data.append(row_data)
    
df = pd.DataFrame(data)
df['report'] = str(targets_in_dir[1])
final_df = interim_df.append(df)
print (targets_in_dir[1])
```

Once I pack it into a loop (see below) which iterates through the filenames specified in `target_in_dir` list my `final_df` is always empty. How can I fix this? I want my `final_df` to contain all the rows extracted from the same table in all the files.

```
for idx, c in enumerate(targets_in_dir):
    try:
        document = Document(c)
        table = document.tables[2]
        processed_files.append(c)
    except: 
        error_log.append(c)
        
        data = []
                
        keys = None
        for i, row in enumerate(table.rows):
            text = (cell.text for cell in row.cells)

            if i == 0:
                keys = tuple(text)
                continue
            row_data = dict(zip(keys, text))
            data.append(row_data)
                 
        df = pd.DataFrame(data)
        df['report'] = str(c)
        final_df.append(df)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`final_df.append(df)` does not change `final_df` in place.

Try changing to `final_df = final_df.append(df)`, this will update `final_df` within the loop.

Pandas [append documentation](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.append.html) contains a note on this:

> Unlike the append() method, which appends to the original list and returns None, append() here does not modify df1 and returns its copy with df2 appended.

Comment: @Martyn is also correct, the indentation seems wrong

Answer (score 0):

If your code is exactly as it is represented in your question, the code which processes the data is indented such that it is executed only as part of the exception handling.

Moving the code to the left by one indent will ensure that it is executed as part of the for loop but outside of the try and exception handling blocks.